# Combine 3 tables with sum mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

I have a problem with my query. I've managed to display data from 2 tables. Next I want to add up SALE_AMT from the 3rd table, the problem is that order by cannot, the program output adds up all data not by order by

This my query:

```
SELECT 
    customer.CUST_NO, customer.CUST_NM, 
    store.STR_CD, store.STR_NM, SUM(SALE_AMT)
FROM 
    customer, store, cust_sale_pnt 
GROUP BY 
    CUST_NO
```

[table customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrM1U.png)

[table cust_sale_pnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZghf.png)

[table store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxpVu.png)

My result

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j52I.png)

Can you guys help me to sum data based on grouping cust_no?

Comment: Please don't post images, text is the only thing we need. Take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't specify a condition that's used to combine the records of the different tables. In effect, you're creating a 'cross join'.

That is, any record of table customer is combined with any record of table store and the result is combined with any record of table cust_sale_pnt.

In effect, you get each of your 3 customers combined with each of your 6 sales. Therefore the sum over sale_amt is identical for each customer.

You want an INNER JOIN to combine the records:

```
SELECT c.CUST_NO, c.CUST_NM, SUM(csp.SALE_AMT) 
  FROM customer c
 INNER JOIN cust_sale_pnt csp ON c.CUST_NO = csp.CUST_NO
 INNER JOIN store ON csp.STR_CD = store.STR_CD
 GROUP BY c.CUST_NO, c.CUST_NM;
```

Comment: Depends. If the fields are aggregated values (like e.g. `MAX(csp.SALE_AMT)`) it's enough to add them to the SELECT clause. Otherwise add them to the GROUP BY clause, too.